# Custom plugin appears outside of the sidebar container

Tags: plugins, widgets

I created a custom plugin that activates a custom contact form widget, and when I add it to my sidebar, it appears outside of the sidebar container.

Here's the code for calling the sidebar:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
```

Here's the visual part of the widget:  (It's not done yet)

```
  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo $before_widget;
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

    if (!empty($title))
      echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;;

    // WIDGET CODE GOES HERE
?>
    <form>
        <lable>First Name</lable>
        <input type="text" id="firstname" />
    </form>
<?php

    echo $after_widget;
  }
```

How it appears:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    //search form code here
</div>
<div class="contact....>
     //contact form code here
</div>
```

What could possibly cause it to behave like that?

P.S: If anything else is needed, let me know.

Comment: Browsers sometimes show something like this in DevTools, when there are errors in HTML. Are you showing output of DevTools or View source method?

Comment: Yea, I use Chrome. I double checked my HTML, though...

Comment: Nevermind! Found the mistake! I edited the search form in my functions.php file, and apparently I left out a closing <div> tag, which resulted in this behavior. Sorry and thanks!